# Importing model trained in Keras as .pb file

Tags: android, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning

I have a trained face recognition system using Keras on my Ubuntu machine. I am facing certain issues regarding deploying it to Android. As of now, android does not support Keras or TFlearn. I need to convert the Keras model into .pb file for the deployment. Can anyone help me with deployment of a manually trained model on android ?

Comment: Have you checked this blogpost http://blog.stratospark.com/creating-a-deep-learning-ios-app-with-keras-and-tensorflow.html?

Comment: Thanks @marcopah ! It is an excellent resource for deployment. I will give everything an in-depth read.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? I'm facing that exact thing right now

Comment: Tensorflow Lite facilitates the deployment of tf.keras model on Android. Go through the [Tensorflow lite guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/object_detection/overview) on object detection model. Thanks!